# Landing page creation in liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay-6

My requirement is when ever user logins into portal with different user (user group mapped) it will displayed their home page(not default home page)
For Ex:Enrollee login with his credentials he may see his home page instead of default home page
is this requirement we can do it in liferay6.2?

Comment: For more details:https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/37630937

Comment: Visit link : https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/17676547